# Multiple kubernetes ingress with same host failing on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy with the following config

```
- different APIs
- different deployment and service
- different bitbucket repos
- different ports
- same host
- same namespace
- same EKS cluster
```

Ingress 1:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: sample-ingress-1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "sample-host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /some(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: some-svc
            port: 
              number: 8585
tls:
 - hosts:
    - "sample-host"
```

Ingress 2:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: sample-ingress-2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "sample-host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /another_url(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: another-svc
            port: 
              number: 8080
tls:
 - hosts:
    - "sample-host"
```

It works `fine` when I deploy the `first api`, but when I deploy the `second api`, the `first api` stops working. Its like the ingress is getting updated which renders the `first api` not working.

Any suggestions to solve this issue will be very helpful